# Use fgetc to get the number of rows in C

Tags: c, string, fgets

My data is as follows:

```
0.05 1.3
0.09 1.8
0.12 1.9
```

I create two variables x and y to store them respectively.

```
    FILE *fp_data;
    double *x;
    double *y;
    int data_size;
    char ch;
    int i;

    fp_data = fopen(path, "r");
    while( ( ch = fgetc(fp_data)) != EOF) if(ch=='\n') ++data_size;

    if (!fp_data)
    {
        printf("Data file cannot open...\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {   
        x = (double*)malloc(data_size * sizeof(double));
        y = (double*)malloc(data_size * sizeof(double));
        
        printf("\n%d\n\n", data_size);
        
        for (i = 0; i < data_size; ++i)
        {
            fscanf(fp_data, "%lf %lf\n", &x[i], &y[i]);

        }
        
        fclose(fp_data);
        
        for (i = 0; i < data_size; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d- %f %f\n", i, x[i], y[i]);
            
        }
    }
```

I notice that my results are wrong like:

```
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000
```

However, if I remove the`while( (ch = fgetc(fp_data)) != EOF ) if(ch=='\n') ++data_size;` code and set `data_size` manually, then everything is fine.

Does anyone know what is the problem of the `fgetc` code?

Comment: I suppose you should rewind() the file. https://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind

Comment: data_size doesn't get properly initialized. You should compile with -Wall and fix all warnings.

Comment: `data_size` isn't initialized. Also, the type of `ch` must have been `int`, not `char`.

Comment: `"Data file cannot open...\n"` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Use `if( (fp_data = fopen(path, "r")) == NULL ){ perror(path); ...`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code.

First, you never initialize the `data_size` variable; this is undefined behaviour: although *some* compilers/platforms *may* set the initial value of such 'automatic' variables to zero, you should ***never*** rely on that. Solution: *explicitly* initialize to zero at the time of declaration: `int data_size = 0;`.

Second, you should check for a failure to open the file *before* any further operations on the `fp_data` file pointer (although I cannot find an *explicit* mention of it in the C Standard, calling `fgetc()` with a `NULL` pointer is likely to cause undefined behaviour). By putting that check in the appropriate place, you can dispense with the `else` conditional block (as your program calls `exit(1)` if the `fopen()` call fails).

Third, **you need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the stream** after your `while ((ch = fgetc(fp_data)) != EOF) ...` loop! Otherwise, you will be attempting to read your data from a file that is already at `EOF`. You can use the [`rewind()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) to do this.

Fourth: Note that the [`fgetc` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`, not a `char`; using a `char` type *can* cause problems in detecting the `EOF` signal

Other points:

1. Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory after use.
2. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)
3. For robustness, use the `size_t` type for `data_size` (and `i`).

Here's a version of your code with the above points address (and commented):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char path[] = "test.txt"; // Or whatever!

int main()
{
    FILE* fp_data;
    double* x;
    double* y;
    size_t data_size = 0; // MUST initialize to zero
    int ch; // Note: "fgetc" return an "int" type, not "char"
    size_t i;

    fp_data = fopen(path, "r");
    if (!fp_data) {
        printf("Data file cannot open...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp_data)) != EOF) if (ch == '\n') ++data_size;

    rewind(fp_data); // MUST rewind the file to the beginning, before reading the data!

    x = malloc(data_size * sizeof(double));
    y = malloc(data_size * sizeof(double));
    printf("\n%zu\n\n", data_size);
    for (i = 0; i < data_size; ++i) { // Use the "%zu" format for "Size_t" types
        fscanf(fp_data, "%lf %lf\n", &x[i], &y[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp_data);

    for (i = 0; i < data_size; ++i) {
        printf("%zu- %f %f\n", i, x[i], y[i]);
    }

    free(x); // Release allocated memory after use.
    free(y);

    return 0;
}
```